# How do I get message contents from channel.history using a Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

I have code that (wants) prints out message history, however I get a barely useful slur of info, IDs and more.

```
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=x name='Cheesebot' discriminator='1916' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=x name='NoLife Minecraft' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=18>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=x name='' discriminator='3912' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=x name='Cheesebot' discriminator='1916' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=x name='NoLife Minecraft' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=18>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=x name='' discriminator='3912' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=x name='' discriminator='3912' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=x name='' discriminator='3912' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=x name='Cheesebot' discriminator='1916' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=x name='NoLife Minecraft' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=18>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=x name='Cheesebot' discriminator='1916' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=x name='NoLife Minecraft' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=18>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=x name='' discriminator='3912' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=x name='general' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=x> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=x name='Cheesebot' discriminator='1916' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=x name='NoLife Minecraft' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=18>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

The code I have right now is this:

```
  async def messagesl(sendc):
    messages = await sendc.history(limit=10).flatten()
    return messages
```

What I need is a way to get the message contents, and other info like user, etc.

sensitive info is an x (or for names, nothing.)

Comment: Could you... show me how to get the message contents please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through the messages and access the attributes you need

```py
messages = await sendc.history(limit=10).flatten()
contents = []

for message in messages:
    contents.append(message.content)
```

If you want a one-liner

```py
contents = [message.content for message in messages]
```

Comment: daaaamn nice one liner

Answer (score 0):

messages is a list of `discord.Message` objects. You'll want to loop through the list and get the `Message.content` of each of them.

---

References

- [`discord.Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20content#discord.Message.content)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the correct way to get chat history in Discord.py is by using a list comprehension with an async for loop. This method allows you to retrieve a specific number of messages from a channel's history.

To do this, you can use the following code:

```
messages = [message async for message in channel.history(limit=123)]
```

It's important to note that this method uses an async for loop, so you will need to make sure your code is within an async function.

You could then simply print the contents:

```
for msg in messages:
    print(msg.content)
```